# try-catch with exceptions defined in template class

Tags: c++, templates, try-catch, nested-class

I'm trying to implement a priority queue using a linked list, but I'm having issues with try/catch. Here are the relevant parts of the priority queue header file:

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUELINKED_H
#define PRIORITYQUEUELINKED_H

    #include "RuntimeException.h"
    #include <list>

    using namespace std;

    template <typename E, typename C>        // uses data type and some total order relation
    class PriorityQueueLinked {

    // code for PriorityQueueLinked

            class EmptyPriorityQueueException : public RuntimeException {
                public:
                    EmptyPriorityQueueException() : 
                                    RuntimeException("Empty priority queue") {}
            };

    // more code

    #endif
```

Here is the RuntimeException header file:

```
#ifndef RUNTIMEEXCEPTION_H_
#define RUNTIMEEXCEPTION_H_

#include <string>

class RuntimeException {// generic run-time exception
private:
    std::string errorMsg;
public:
   RuntimeException(const std::string& err) { errorMsg = err; }
   std::string getMessage() const { return errorMsg; }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const RuntimeException& e)
{
   out << e.getMessage();
   return out;
}

#endif
```

Here is my main:

```
#include "PriorityQueueLinked.h"
#include "Comparator.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        PriorityQueueLinked<int,isLess> prique; // empty priority queue
        prique.removeMin();                    // throw EmptyPriorityQueueException
    }
    catch(...) {
        cout << "error" << endl << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem lies in not being able to configure a replacement for the "..." for catch. I've tried several things, one of them: "catch(PriorityQueueLinked < int,isLess > ::EmptyPriorityQueueException E)", but in this case it says that EmptyPriorityQueueException is not a member of PriorityQueueLinked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Exceptions should derive from `std::exception`. Also, why are you making it an inner class, just define it outside.

Comment: Make EmptyPriorityQueueException public. Currently it's a private nested class, which is not visible from outside.

Comment: **Never ever put `using namespace std;`** in a header file.

Comment: @KerrekSB unless it's within something else that won't have an effect on files that include it, like a class or another namespace.

Comment: If the copy constructor of a class can throw, `terminate()` may be called when you try to throw an instance of it. And the copy constructor of `std::string` may throw, so the same is true of your RuntimeException. Why don't you inherit from `std::runtime_error`, which solves that problem for you, and also ensures you have `std::exception` as a base class?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: By the time you know how to justify exceptions to the rule, Kerrek's comment is no longer targeted at you. :P

Comment: @GMan ah, I can never tell. I've done stupider things. Also I wanted to make sure I was right so I said it in a reply to Kerrek, which, if it were wrong, would come under heavy fire and let me know that I was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try-catch supports inheritance with exception classes. `catch (const RuntimeException & ex)` will catch any subclass of RuntimeException, even if its private. This is the whole point of deriving exception classes.

By the way, never write `using namespace std;` is a header, you can never know who include it, and how. Also the standard library already has your genereal purpose exception class, and what a surprise! They also clall it runtime exception, exception it§s written like this: `std::runtime_exception`. You can find it in `<stdexcept>`.